# Is it possible to read from old version of Kafka and write into new version of Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have a requirement where I have to read from 0.8.2 version of Kafka and process the data and write to 0.10.2 version of Kafka.

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Check Kafka mirroring. More information is available on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330

Comment: Mirroring is useful only in same cluster environment. But in my case, these two Kafkas are different clusters even the version also different.

Answer (score 2):

use kafka MirrorMaker.you can mirror data in 0.8.2 to 0.10.2,then process data in 0.10.2

Answer (score 0):

not sure it's the best option, but you could use 2 machines (not tested):

box 1: consumer then netcat

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper myzookeeper:2181 --topic test --from-beginning | nc 1.2.3.4 5600
```

box 2 (IP 1.2.3.4): netcat then producer

```
nc -l -p 5600 |  bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --zookeeper myotherzookeeper:2181 --topic test
```